# What does 'ata1: soft resetting link' mean in syslog?

Tags: 16.04, sata

In syslog I am seeing messages like below

```
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30354.925789] ata1: soft resetting link
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.093298] ata1: EH complete
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.106165] ata1: soft resetting link
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.273103] ata1: EH complete
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.389621] ata2: soft resetting link
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.553122] ata2: EH complete
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.570366] ata2: soft resetting link
Apr 30 18:55:10 platform2 kernel: [30355.737368] ata2: EH complete
```

Can someone let me know what do these messages mean? Are they dangerous?

Ubuntu Version 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case two drives seems to disconnect and connect again.

This may be caused by loose cable. Make sure that your drive is properly connected to the motherboard. If it's notebook you should be able to disassemble its cover, unplug the drive and plug it again. If it's PC you can try to replace sata cable.

Another thing that may cause this is power saving, especially on laptops. In most cases you can disable such options in your BIOS.

If the problem persists: use SMART monitoring tools to analyze your disk drives.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

Then use it with your drive name.

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdb
```

In most cases ata1 is the first sata device and its block device name is /dev/sda, ata2 is /dev/sdb and so on.

But you can list your drives using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In SMART results look especially for attributes:

```
sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sda
sudo smartctl --attributes /dev/sdb
```

Things like:

```
Reallocated_Sector_Ct
Reallocated_Event_Count
Current_Pending_Sector
```

can idicate your disk drives failing, if their `RAW_VALUE` is above `0`. Basicly this means that your drive have badsectors. Then it's up to you to decide if you want to use it or replace it. It doesn't mean that your drive will stop working right away, but it may eventually - so in this case do your backups.

But it's unlikely that two drives are failing at the same time. So in case of soft resetting link it's rather something with cables, or PC/notebook itself. This might be also caused by failing motherboard or power supply.

Comment: What can happen on the end user side? Can there be loss of data or symbolic links getting lost, etc ?

Comment: Modern file systems should handle bad sectors. But eventually you may face data loss. For example, I'm using such failing disk for two years now, as an additional backup. But I am aware of possible data loss so I don't treat it as my primary data storage and I don't do writes too often. Because at some point it may even stop responding, so the loss of data could be not onl partial, but also complete.

Comment: However as I said, in your case this doesn't seem to be disks that failing.

Comment: About possible data loss: any time hard drive stores any data and responds to kernel that the data has been stored may result in data loss if the hard drive failed to verify the data on disk surface. The bad sectors are usually detected while trying to read the data and in many cases the drive can still read the data after retrying multiple times and then re-allocating that sector from reserve area. If your drive has less than about 5 bad sectors, those may be caused by the manufacturing defects. If you have a lot more, the actual cause may be head failure and then the hard drive may fail fast